# Scrapy's Download_Delay and concurrent requests not working as expected

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Looking at scrapy's documentation for download_delay and Concurrent_requests, what I understand is: if I have 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 25 and download_delay of 1 second, that means that once scrapy requests 25 pages, scrapy will wait for all 25 to download, then wait for 1 seconds, and again request for 25 pages. If I am using download_delay of 0 sec, scrapy does same as above without 1 second delay. But when I used these settings in my scraper, this doesn't work as expected, as when I am 0sec delay, my network usage is 2.1Mbps average when I am using 0 sec delay compared to 1 sec delay when my network usage is just 0.3 Mbps average(0.4Mbps maximum). Here is my code:

```
class DetailsxxxSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "details"
allowed_domains = ["www.xxx.com"]
download_delay = 1
custom_settings = {'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 25}
def start_requests(self):
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///temp.db')
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = DBSession()
    urls = session.query(Temp.url).filter_by(status = "Insert").all()
    # print urls
    for url in urls:
        yield Request(url[0])
```

Crawl rate is 1800 pages/minute average when using 0 second delay, and when using 1 second delay is 43 pages/minute though the pages/minute rate ideally should be 900 pages/minute. It seems like download_delay is being set up per request when using 1 second delay.

I am using proxies for every request I make. What am I missing?
Is there a way that I can set Delay after 25 requests to be a 1 second.
I ideally want the speed of 900 page/minute. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The download_delay is the amount of time it will wait between consecutive requests from the same website in seconds

So if you will  use download_delay=1, you will always have
 <60  pages/minute. (43 in your case)

To get 900 page/minute, you should use:

download_delay < (60/900) < 0.067

My guess would be to try around 0.05

Comment: Is there a way I can set download delay after 25 requests to be 1 second, rather than set delay between each consecutive requests?

Comment: It does not seem that this can be done through scrappy settings